# classes in jar are not accessible during war deployment in Wildfly

Tags: jboss, dependencies, wildfly

I am trying to migrate my application server from JBoss4 to Wildfly 9. The structure of my war is

```
myWar.war
      - WEB-INF
           -lib
               -jar1   
               -jar2
```

When I deploy this war in Wildfly, classes inside these jars are not accessible (ClassNotFoundException).

After reading more about Wildfly, I learnt that classloading is changed in Wildfly and dependencies need to be explicitly mentioned in file jboss-deployment-structure.xml or in Manifest.mf

I am a little confused and have 2 questions -

1. Is it required to specify this dependency in
   jboss-deployment-structure.xml or manifest.mf (as the jars within
   the war's lib) ?
2. If yes, how to exactly specify this dependency of jars ? I tried some ways of mentioning dependencies by their jar names/package
   names in jboss-deployment-structure.xml, etc but with no luck
   (everytime I get missing dependencies or module not found exception,
   etc)

Do I have to create a module under Wildfly's modules directory also ? But these jars are dynamically created and packaged in war file with my build scripts, so I cannot place jars under modules folder (like quartz or mysql jars) as these are not static.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

jars inside the war's lib folder don´t need to be declared in MANIFEST.MF or jboss-deployment-structure.xml.

Those files are used to declare dependencies to wildfly modules (for example jdbc driver, cxf dependencies, etc).

Are you sure your ClassNotFoundException comes from jars included in your war's lib folder? You don´t need to do anything special to load classes from the lib folder of your war.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with wildfly, I have Gson as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly 9 do expect a particular-way structured web-archives. From the war structure every thing looks fine. Do re-check the war structure is in conformance with Widfly 9. Right structure should be like :

```
myWar.war
 ---WEB-INF
    ------- lib
           ---- Jar 1
           ---- Jar 2
    -------- classes
           ---- Your classeses here
    -------- web.xml
```